# uLogin в Kohana: как установить?

Tags: ulogin, авторизация, kohana

Сабж... Кто нибудь делал? Вот этот модуль:
https://github.com/ulogin/ulogin-Kohana

Инфы на гитхабе как-то маловато по установке.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

1. Создать таблицу ulogins:

   CREATE TABLE `ulogins` (
       `id` INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
       `network` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
       `identity` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
       UNIQUE INDEX `identity` (`identity`)
   )
2. Добавить 'ulogins' => array(), в protected $_has_many у модели user

Comment: Никак не могу понять второй пункт, модель user сам создаешь?